# How can I use mysqli_stmt_bind_param for integers?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

As I now know, `mysqli_real_escape_string` is not as secure as prepared statements so I'm making the switch.
However I've run across a slight issue with the simplest bit of code.
The query I am expecting to be executed is `SELECT * from forums WHERE id=1` and testing this against the database rows are found.

This is the prepared statement code I am using.

```
$con=mysqli_connect('a','b','c','d');
$forum = $_GET["forum"];
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * from forums WHERE id=?");
echo mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $forum);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt)<1){
    echo "0";
    }
```

This seems to return 10 which means the query binded successfully but no rows where found.

I'm sorry if this may seem trivial, but this doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: what is `$_GET['forum']`?  Are you sure there are results for it?

Comment: @ExplosionPills this code worked when I was using the normal mysqli extensions

Comment: Why do you think your problem is mysqli_stmt_bind_param related?

Comment: Because mysqli_query worked fine with this code

Comment: You're treating a prepared statement as if it was a result. I don't think this has any hope of working in its current form. A lot of this stems from using the old-school procedural style where it's easy to make mistakes of this sort.

Comment: @tadman, that's all well and good, but I would like it to return a result so I can use it

Comment: See example 5 in [the `mysqli` documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you also need `mysqli_stmt_bind_result`, `mysqli_stmt_store_result` and `mysqli_stmt_fetch` to get some results out... At least this is what the manual says.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use [`mysqli_stmt_store_result`](http://php.net/mysqli_stmt_store_result), [`mysqli_stmt_num_rows`](http://php.net/mysqli_stmt_num_rows) will return 0 because mysqli hasn't yet fetched the data and doesn't know how many rows there are.

[`mysqli_stmt_store_result`](http://php.net/mysqli_stmt_store_result) buffers all the resulting data from MySQL in memory for subsequent use by PHP but it can result in out-of-memory errors with large datasets or low memory limits.

Comment: mysqli_stmt_store_result doesn't exist. Closest matches:

Comment: I've edited the question adding these functions in but nothing happens